# DateTime with Angular (use DatePipe correctly)

Tags: angular, date, pipe

I have the following Date in this format:

```
event.timestamp = 2020-12-18T20:33:14.2174666+00:00
```

Can somebody please tell me whats the correct date that should be displayed? (I am a little bit confused because of the 2174666+00:00 - what does this number say and how to transform it correctly?

```
Act code: {{event.timestamp | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2020-12-18T20:33:14.2174666+00:00` means `12/18/2020 21:33:14` (and BTW that's what  `{{event.timestamp | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}` should give you.

for the last two parts:

- `2174666` is the milli-seconds fraction
- `+00:00` is the offset hours to calculate (from time in **GMT**, aka: **UTC**, aka: **Zulu** time)

The following snippet would give you :  `2020-12-18T20:33:14.217Z` (Z: is in Zulu time)

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-12-18T20:33:14.2174666+00:00').toJSON())
```

Comment: ok thanks - so the correct date which should be displayed is +1 hour - right?

Comment: AFAIK, DatePipe uses locale to display date in user's timezone